# Filter by unique values in column and apply function seperately

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, filter, lambda

I have a dataframe df where df.head() which looks like

| category | value | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | 10:15 |
| B | 5 | 10:20 |
| B | 5 | 12:30 |
| Z | 6 | 12:45 |
| S | 5 | 13:45 |

I have a pre-existing function def op(df): which has a different calculation for each category which I want to apply separately when the category is filled with for example only A, then it is filled with on B and so on.

Basically, the function should be applied to each filtered dataframe containing each category value.

I tried applying the function separately for each category but it does not seem efficient

```
df_A = df[df.category=='A']
df_A = op(df_A)
df_B = df[df.category=='B']
df_B = op(df_B)
..
..
..
df_Z = df[df.category=='Z']
df_Z = op(df_Z)
final_df = pd.concat[df_A,df_B,....df_Z]
```

Question: How do I apply the function to each value in the column separately more efficiently, for example if there are more than 50 categories?

NOTE: Because of the time column, groupby is not the right option, each category of same value is different. Therefore the GROUP BY does not work

Comment: If your `op` function knows what to do for each `category` why can't you just do `final_df = op(df)`?

Comment: You want to `groupby.apply`: `df.groupby('category').apply(op)`, or similar depending on the function and exact expected output

Comment: the function uses the time feature as well, hence it would be different for every category and cannot be applied together in one line at the end. The aim is to filter the dataframe for each category and apply the function to the filtered dataframe in a more clean and efficient way.